# NETLOGON trying to register with incorrect DNS server?

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns, netlogon

So, I have a Domain Controller `DOMAINSERVER`, and a second domain controller `DS1`. They are part of the domain `office.mydomainname.com`, and all was well in the world; DNS server was working great, Clients could talk to the domain, sunshine and daisies all around.

Then the extended power outage happened and the two domain controllers became islands in their own fear-filled boxen.

The first issue encountered is that the DNS server service is not starting properly because it can't determine that it's in the domain (I guess?) and so refuses to cooperate with directory services, and the directory won't start because it can't talk to DNS because neither servers are starting them up!

The closest I've come as far as diagnostics is that for some reason NETLOGON is trying to register records with a public nameserver (?!?!) and failing.

My question is: How do I tell NETLOGON that it really should be using the adapter-configured DNS server to register to?

I've been scratching all sorts of settings trying to figure out how to get things back and working for hours.

For clarity, both domain controllers have the other set as the primary DNS server, and themselves as secondary, and neither are properly serving DNS at the moment.

Edit: I've managed to massage the servers so they're at least serving DNS properly again, but they're still trying to register their entries in the public DNS, which is fine (for a while) because said entries don't change often, but this is still an ongoing issue (just not so urgent anymore).

Comment: What does each Domain Controller use for primary and secondary DNS in the TCPv4 properties of the NIC?

Comment: As mentioned, they each have the other server's IP as their primary DNS server, and their own IP address as secondary.

Comment: For example, `DOMAINSERVER` has IP x.199 and `DS1` has x.203, `DOMAINSERVER` has x.203 as primary and x.199 for secondary, and vice-versa for `DS1`.